# TSC throws "Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant" error in TypeScript Playground

Tags: typescript, typescript-playground

When I wrote below destructuring assignment code in TypeScript Playground.

```
const a = { name: 'teresa teng' };

let name;
({ name } = a);

console.log(name);
```

TSC throws:

> 'name' is deprecated.(6385)

> lib.dom.d.ts(17642, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

> Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant.(2588)

It works fine when I change the `name` to some "unique" name like `userName`. So I think some global variables are defined in TypeScript Playground, they are conflicts, right? If so, what are they?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jMcC2BTAXDAcimwCdsIFiwBzAmAXwG4AoZgG21gxxYAo1u2BkngBKFs1CQQHAHRsQ1XoPHMgA)

Comment: Ah, the joys of the browser global environment. You can't declare a global variable called `name`, it's a predefined property of the `window` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name If that code were in a module, or a function, or even just a scoping block, it would be fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/N4KABBYMYPYHYGcAuYCGYC8ZhjqgtgKYBcYA5EoQE6ELqVwDmZYAvgNwjiQA2hKeIp0hgAFDkGE2mNAEpO3CLEQw+AOh4xGoyfJCsgA

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it. Thanks. I thought it runs in some kind of sandbox or NodeJS module scope, not the browser global scope.

Comment: That's an interesting point. I don't see an option to control what the context of the code is in the playground. There's an option to control what the *output* module format is, but... I never noticed that before. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Or using a top-level `export {}` to make this file as a module. "In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well)."

Comment: Of course! No *setting* for it, but anything with `import` or `export`... :-)